# High-performance Academic Server

Tags: php, webserver, high-availability

Suppose I want to build a server for the university's academic interests. The server is dedicated only to a site, where users (students and lecturers) just view and fill the academic data. But at a time (e.g. once a semester), about **12,000 students or more** will access the site **simultaneously**. The most common activity is authentication (login/logout) and read/write the database (view/submit forms).

The following hardware and software used:

- 4-core latest generation Desktop CPU with Integrated Graphics
- motherboard with one standard Gigabit Ethernet
- 16 GB DDR3 1600 MHz
- 240 GB Solid-State Drive
- Windows 7 operating system (chosen because TRIM support for SSD)
- PHP programming language

Due to resource limitations, then the university can not provide "server-grade" hardware. But I should be able to choose the right software, which can handle thousands of connections without having a crash/hang/down (you know what I mean). Especially when all students are using it.

After doing a little research, I have selected the following candidates. But with little experience, I would like to ask the expert programming through this site. Please do not close this question, because the question is still included in the category "*software tools commonly used by programmers*" and "*practical, answerable That problems are unique to the programming profession*" (see FAQ). I expect an answer from the various perspective and expertise.

1. I am interested in using the nginx web server because it is
   specifically made for high-traffic website? How do you think?
2. I was thinking maybe using the Berkeley DB (from Oracle) will be
   faster than MySQL? Is this true?
3. Should I use PHP version 5.3 or 5.4? Why?
4. Rather than confuse to choose to use APC / eAccelerator / XCache,
   Apache / nginx / lighttpd or other, better for me to use Zend Server
   Community Edition (complete with Apache, PHP, Zend Optmizer, MySQL)?
   Is this a better option?

Thank you for your answer and hopefully benefit us all.

Comment: I'm a very low level PHP / database programmer, but in Objective-C less = faster. I'm not sure if that counts but it *may* be an idea

Comment: Great question -- wording, format, etc.  This may belong at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Alot of it does come down to source code, but you can limit what an app is doing, for example limit the memory usage and cpu cycles of certain users on the machine. Would definitely go the linux route though... It may be more hassle at first, but there's a lot more support out there from the community on linux distros

Comment: Are you serving static content? Is it read-instensive? Is it write-intensive? What does the site do?